# How to test if an advertisement is not being served by iAd?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

How to test with simulator the advertisement that is not being served by iAd?

I already implemented the code with the help of the documentation, but now, how to test it, especially this delegate:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps trying your app without an internet connection will fire that delegate ?

Comment: yes, it works, even though it goes not generate the correct error code. Thanks for the idea.